# AS3 Callback from Server Not Working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-media-server

I have code that makes a call to my `main.acs` and then broadcasts a message out to all the users.  When I broadcast my message out to all users, the bcStopStreaming function never gets called.

Server Side code:

```
application.onConnect = function(client) {
    application.acceptConnection(client);

    client.stopStreaming = function() {
        trace("#stopStreaming# called");
        application.broadcastMsg("bcStopStreaming");
    }

    client.startStreaming = function() {
        trace("#startStreaming# called");
        application.broadcastMsg("bcStreaming");
    }
}
```

Connect Button:

```
public function btnConnectHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);

    nc.connect("rtmp://"+hostName+"/test");
    nc.client = new Object();

    nc.client.bcStreaming = function(){
        trace("Started Streaming");
    };

    nc.client.bcStopStreaming = function(){
        trace("Stopped Streaming");
    };
}
```

Disconnect Button:

```
public function btnDisconnectHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    nc.call("stopStreaming", null);
    nc.close();
}
```

Error I get:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled AsyncErrorEvent:. text=Error #2095: flash.net.NetConnection was unable to invoke callback bcStreaming. error=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property bcStreaming not found on test and there is no default value.
at test/btnConnectHandler()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client is not set up correctly.
And please stop using inline functions.

```
public function btnConnectHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);

    nc.connect("rtmp://"+hostName+"/test");
    var myClient = new Object()

    myClient.bcStreaming = this.bcStreaming;
    myClient.bcStopStreaming = this.bcStopStreaming;
    nc.client = myClient;
}
public function bcStreaming(){
    trace("Started Streaming");
}

public function bcStopStreaming(){
    trace("Stopped Streaming");
}
```

[nc.client](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#client)